# Compile-time (constexpr) float modulo?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, floating-point, modulo

Consider the following function that computes the integral or floating-point modulo depending on the argument type, at compile-time:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T modulo(const T x, const T y)
{
    return (std::is_floating_point<T>::value) ? (x < T() ? T(-1) : T(1))*((x < T() ? -x : x)-static_cast<long long int>((x/y < T() ? -x/y : x/y))*(y < T() ? -y : y))
    : (static_cast<typename std::conditional<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int, T>::type>(x)
      %static_cast<typename std::conditional<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int, T>::type>(y));
}
```

Can the body of this function be improved ? (I need to have a single function for both integer and floating-point types).

Comment: what do you mean by "improved"? made shorter?

Comment: Shorter/Cleaner/More robust (is it possible to avoid the `static_cast` ?)...

Comment: just to say one, you could use template aliases to make the `static_cast<typename<...` part more readable

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use template specialisation for this case (e.g. enable_if)? That would make for a clearer implementation and it could be called as if it were a single function.

Comment: Specialization would be a lot cleaner and more concise.

Comment: @KerrekSB: you really mean specialization or rather overload?

Comment: Imho `return (x < 0 ? -1 : 1) * (abs(x) - (int64_t)abs(x / y) * abs(y));` is much more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to clean this up:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cmath>

template <typename T>  //     integral?       floating point?
bool remainder_impl(T a, T b, std::true_type, std::false_type) constexpr
{
    return a % b;  // or whatever
}

template <typename T>  //     integral?        floating point?
bool remainder_impl(T a, T b, std::false_type, std::true_type) constexpr
{
    return std::fmod(a, b); // or substitute your own expression
}

template <typename T>
bool remainder(T a, T b) constexpr
{
    return remainder_impl<T>(a, b,
             std::is_integral<T>(), std::is_floating_point<T>());
}
```

If you try and call this function on a type that's not arithmetic, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Oh, no, I had missed that. I'll make a note. Thanks.

Comment: @TBohne There's no indication that fmod is a constexpr, yet this seems to work just fine in MinGW 4.9.2.  Raises my eyebrow...

Comment: In MSVC intellisense this won't work, fmod is not constexpr. But it compiles. Go figure

Answer (score 2):

I would rather define it this way (template aliases + template overloading):

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

// For floating point types

template<typename T, typename enable_if<is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* p = nullptr>
constexpr T modulo(const T x, const T y)
{
    return (x < T() ? T(-1) : T(1)) * (
            (x < T() ? -x : x) -
            static_cast<long long int>((x/y < T() ? -x/y : x/y)) * (y < T() ? -y : y)
            );
}

// For non-floating point types

template<typename T>
using TypeToCast = typename conditional<is_floating_point<T>::value, int, T>::type;

template<typename T, typename enable_if<!is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* p = nullptr>
constexpr T modulo(const T x, const T y)
{
    return (static_cast<TypeToCast<T>>(x) % static_cast<TypeToCast<T>>(y));
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int x = modulo(7.0, 3.0);
    static_assert((x == 1.0), "Error!");
    return 0;
}
```

It is lengthier but cleaner IMO. I am assuming that by "single function" you mean "something that can be invoked uniformly". If you mean "a single function *template*", then I would just keep the template alias improvement and leave the overload. But then, as mentioned in another answer, it would not be clear why you do *need* to have one single function template.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class T>
constexpr
T
modulo(T x, T y)
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
                                        int,
                                        T
                                     >::type Int;
    return std::is_floating_point<T>() ?
              x - static_cast<long long>(x / y) * y :
              static_cast<Int>(x) % static_cast<Int>(y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask,

> “Can the body of this function be improved?”

Certainly. Right now it is a spaghetti mess:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T modulo(const T x, const T y)
{
    return (std::is_floating_point<T>::value) ? (x < T() ? T(-1) : T(1))*((x < T() ? -x : x)-static_cast<long long int>((x/y < T() ? -x/y : x/y))*(y < T() ? -y : y))
    : (static_cast<typename std::conditional<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int, T>::type>(x)
      %static_cast<typename std::conditional<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int, T>::type>(y));
}
```

You clarify that …

> “(I need to have a single function for both integer and floating-point types)”

Well the template **is not** a single function. It’s a template. Functions are generated from it.

This means your question builds on a false assumption.

With that assumption removed, one way to simplify the function body, which you should do as a matter of course, is to specialize the template for floating point types versus other numeric types. To do that put the function template implementation in a class (because C++ does not support partial specialization of functions, only of classes).

Then you can employ various *formatting tricks*, including the "0?0 : blah" trick to make the function more readable, with lines and *indentation* and stuff! :-)

---

**Addendum**: delving into your code I see that you cast haphazardly to `long int` and `int` with disregard of the invoker's types. That's ungood. It is probably a good idea to write up a bunch of automated test cases, invoking the function with various argument types and big/small values.

Comment: +1: Discarding the broken original premise is an important point

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is simpler:

```
// Special available `%`
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto modulo(T const& x, U const& y) -> decltype(x % y) {
    return x % y;
}
```

Note: based on detection of `%` so also works for custom types as long as they implement the operator. I also made it mixed type while I was at it.

```
// Special floating point
inline constexpr float modulo(float x, float y) { return /*something*/; }

inline constexpr double modulo(double x, double y) { return /*something*/; }

inline constexpr long double modulo(long double x, long double y) { return /*something*/; }
```

Note: it would cleaner to have `fmod` available unfortunately I do not believe it is `constexpr`; therefore I chose to have non-template modulos for the floating point types which allows you to perform *magic* to compute the exact modulo possibly based on the binary representation of the type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that much simpler if you want:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
constexpr auto Modulo(const A& a, const B& b) -> decltype(a - (b * int(a/b)))
{
    return a - (b * int(a/b));
}
```